# Moving site - make all links 301 on same tld

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, top-level-domains

Customer had website in Joomla like this:

- `www.example.com/home/`
- `www.domainA.com/home/aboutus`
- `www.domainA.com/home/blog`

Not sure why it was made this way with /home as default.

Anyway I moved the site and domain to new hosting and now I have lost `/home`.  Meaning that all the links are gone. Now I have:

- `www.domainA.com`
- `www.domainA.com/aboutus`
- `www.domainA.com/blog`

I would like to to redirect everything that started with `/home` to exact same links but without `/home` with 301 or whatever solution is best.

I guess it should be possible with webmaster tools and somehow in .htaccess so that users or links present on web also get redirected immediately ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your root .htaccess, using mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /home /
```

However, if you are already using mod_rewrite (very likely that you are if this is still a Joomla site) then you should use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Nothing else to do in Google Search Console (formerly known as "Google Webmaster Tools").

Comment: Added mod_alias alternative - which would be preferable if you aren't currently using mod_rewrite.